# How to look up a space in a field value and display all characters before it

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm personalizing an email based on a `First_Name` field, however, due to some email capture forms that only have a `Full_Name` field rather than it split out between two fields, first and last name, I'm trying to figure out how to ONLY display the first name from the `Full_Name` field. For example:

`Full_Name: Jane Doe`

I just want "Jane" to display in the email. Is there an AMPScript function that can be used similarly to the LEFT function in Excel to look up the space and display the characters before it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mix of [Substring](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/string/Substring.html) and [Index of](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/string/IndexOf.html)

So use something like this:

```
Set @name = Full_Name
var @index
Set @index = IndexOf(@name,' ')
var @length
set @length = Length(@name)
%%=Substring(@name,@index,@length)=%%
```

*first time with ampscript

Or you can use something like this in Apex:

```
public String[] split(String regExp)

For example, for String s = 'boo:and:foo':
s.split(':', 2) results in {'boo', 'and:foo'}
s.split(':', 5) results in {'boo', 'and', 'foo'}
s.split(':', -2) results in {'boo', 'and', 'foo'}
s.split('o', 5) results in {'b', '', ':and:f', '', ''}
s.split('o', -2) results in {'b', '', ':and:f', '', ''}
s.split('o', 0) results in {'b', '', ':and:f'}
```

for your case you can do the following:

```
String s = 'John Doe':
s.split(' ', 2) results in {'John', 'Doe'}
```

Comment: The only issue is if the person has two first names, e.g. "Mary Jane McManperson" - with the above you would only get "Mary".

Comment: @Gortonington yea exactly, but that's what he wanted...

Comment: @raym0nd The first example in AMPscript you provided works, but it only displays the last name, or everything after the space in the name. If I change it to: %%=Substring(@name,1,@index)=%% that will display the first name. Thanks so much for your help! Didn't mean to duplicate a question, I just didn't find the help I was looking for previously.

Comment: Actually I do have one more follow up question...%%=Substring(@name,1,@index)=%% includes the space after the first name. Does AMPscript allow you to do something like @index -1 or anything?

Comment: %%=Substring(@name,1,Subtract(@index,1))=%%